# commutative rsa in node js

Tags: node.js, rsa

I am trying to use the node js library `node-rsa` to encrypt and decrypt with two keys commutatively. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa')
const key1 = new NodeRSA({b: 512})
const key2 = new NodeRSA({b: 512})

const e0 = 'Hello RSA!'

const e1 = key1.encrypt(e0, 'base64')
const e2 = key2.encrypt(e1, 'base64')

const e3 = key2.decrypt(e2, 'utf8')
const e4 = key1.decrypt(e3, 'utf8')

console.log(e4)
```

I want to be able to switch the decrpytion order like so:

```
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa')
const key1 = new NodeRSA({b: 512})
const key2 = new NodeRSA({b: 512})

const e0 = 'Hello RSA!'

const e1 = key1.encrypt(e0, 'base64')
const e2 = key2.encrypt(e1, 'base64')

const e3 = key1.decrypt(e2, 'utf8')
const e4 = key2.decrypt(e3, 'utf8')

console.log(e4) // this should return 'Hello RSA!' just like before
```

I believe this should be possible because rsa is commutative however this doesn't work, I get an error when I run this code. How can I modify it so that it will work?

Comment: You have misunderstood how RSA's commutativity works. Not like this.

Comment: could you give an example of how it can work?

Comment: (a^e) * (b^e) = (a*b)^e mod N.

Comment: could you give an example of how it could work with code?